# WP_Query to loop a Custom Field, Custom Post Types do not show

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, loop

I am using WP_Query to loop a Custom Field, Custom Post Type that shows 6 Menu Icons across 6 horizontal fields.  The icons do not show on the page.

My query code is:

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'course_feature', 'orderby', => 'post_id', 'order' => 'ASC')); ?>
```

code to show loop:

```
<?php while( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
<div class="col-sm-2">
<i class=<?php the_field('course_feature_icon'); ?>"</i>
</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a missing opening quote and closing bracket on this line:

```
<i class=<?php the_field('course_feature_icon'); ?>"</i>
```

Needs to be:

```
<i class="<?php the_field('course_feature_icon'); ?>"></i>
```

That's all that's wrong with your code. It should then work assuming:

1. You have a custom field, `course_feature_icon`, whose value is a valid CSS class.
2. You have the necessary CSS to add an icon based on that class.

One last suggestion though. For safety you should [escape](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/theme-security/data-sanitization-escaping/) the field value before outputting it as a class:

```
<i class="<?php echo esc_attr( get_field('course_feature_icon') ); ?>"></i>
```

Comment: The icons still do not show. The course_features titles show but the corresponding icons do not show.

Comment: There's nothing invalid about your code if you fix the issue I identified, which means your issue is either 1 or 2 of the points I raised in my answer.

Comment: `the_field` could be unidentified

Comment: That’s an Advanced Custom Fields function. If you’re not using that plugin you can’t use it.

Answer (score 0):

The icons still do not show. The course_features titles that appear beneath each icon shows, but the icons do not show.

So, I have 6 columns of text, but the icons do not appear above the text. Not sure what to do … I tried the suggested edits. The icons do not show.

I have them as a custom field group: course_feature_icon, field type: Radio button, choices: .ci ci-computer, and 5 additional names. (css icon sprite name).